# react-native build successful but shown nothing

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm facing an error from the last day and I could not resolve this, so I decided to share on this network.
actually, I started work in react-native and was running the application very smoothly but now I don't know what is the problem in the code, by facing the issue `"activity class {...} does not exist",` but in a directory, the same file on the same path exists too, and as a result, build failed...

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbTlW.jpg)

Comment: I try to cloned from previous state too, but error is not resolved...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to clean gradlew cache:

```
cd @projectDir/android
```

and then

```
./gradlew clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the android and ios folders and files again. "react-native upgrade" should do the work for you - provided you have not changed anything in the generated files.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

or

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

clean cache memory and delete the previously installed application from your device.